# como puedo deshabilitar y habilitar un input type submit una vez ya han sido utilizado por el usuario pero sin quitarle la funcion?

Tags: javascript, php, html

Este es un código HTML que contiene un formulario para un chatbot que se comunica con una base de datos. El formulario tiene un campo de entrada para el RUT del usuario y un botón de enviar llamado "VALIDAR". Si el usuario ingresa un RUT válido, el chatbot buscará en la base de datos una respuesta relacionada con ese RUT y la mostrará en la sección de mensajes. Si se encuentra una respuesta, se ofrecerán dos opciones al usuario, "SI" y "NO", que se pueden usar para aceptar o rechazar una oferta respectivamente. Si el usuario hace clic en "SI", se actualizará el estado del registro en la base de datos y se mostrará un mensaje de confirmación. Si el usuario hace clic en "NO", se mostrará un mensaje de agradecimiento.

estoy buscando como puedo deshabilitarlos sin quitarle la función que con lleva, ósea que cuando el usuario de click en "SI" le muestre un mensaje y se deshabilite el boton NO permanentemente y viceversa pero como son submit me quita función

````
<head>
<title> chat bot</title>
<meta charset ="utf-8">

</head>
<body >

<form id = "mi-formulario" method ="post" align ="center">

<h1>CHAT BOT</h1>

<label for="nombre">Rut:</label>
<input type ="number" id = "rut" name ="rut" placeholder ="Favor ingrese su rut" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['rut']) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['rut']) : ''; ?>" required >
<input id = "VALIDAR"  class ="btn" type ="submit" type ="button"name ="VALIDAR" value = "Ingresar" >
<br></br>
<div  id = "mensajes" name ="mensajes" class = "mensajes" > 
<?php



if (isset($_POST['VALIDAR'])) { /*boton que envía mensaje al div*/
require("con_db.php");
$con = Conectar();
$id = $_POST['rut'];
$SQL = 'SELECT id, response, oferta2, oferta3, Estado FROM chat WHERE response =:doc';
$stmt = $con-> prepare ($SQL);
$result = $stmt->execute(array(':doc'=>$id));
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

if(count($rows)){
    foreach ($rows AS $row){
        echo "".$row->oferta2."<br>";
        
    }
    
    
}else{
    echo"rut no existe";
    
    
}
    
}


if (isset($_POST['SI'])) { /*botón que da respuesta pero necesito que se desactive al momento de dar click
  $rut = $_POST['rut'];
  
  $dsn = 'mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=chatbot';
  $usuario = 'root';
  $contrasena = '';
  $opciones = array(
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false
  );
  
  try {
    $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $usuario, $contrasena, $opciones);
    
    $sql = "UPDATE chat SET Estado = '1' WHERE response = :rut";
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam(':rut', $rut, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->execute();
    
    echo 'Su oferta ha sido Aceptada.';

  } catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Error al actualizar el estado: ' . $e->getMessage();
  }
}
if (isset($_POST['NO'])) { //botón que da respuesta pero necesito que se desactive al momento de dar click
    
    
  echo 'Muchas gracias por su tiempo.';


}




?>


</div>

<div style="text-align: center; margin-top: 20px;">
 <input id="SI" class="btn2"  type="submit" name="SI" value="SI" />
<input id="NO" class="btn2"  type="submit" name="NO" value="NO"/>
</div>
</form>
<script>
const submitBtnSI = document.getElementById("SI");
const submitBtnNO = document.getElementById("NO");

submitBtnSI.addEventListener("click", function() {
 submitBtnNO.setAttribute("disabled", "true");
 alert("Click en SI");
});

submitBtnNO.addEventListener("click", function() {
 submitBtnSI.setAttribute("disabled", "true");
 alert("Click en NO");
});
</script>


</body>


</html>```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo puedes hacer así:

```js
const submitBtnSI = document.getElementById("SI");
const submitBtnNO = document.getElementById("NO");

submitBtnSI.addEventListener("click", function() {
 submitBtnNO.setAttribute("disabled", "true");
 alert("Click en SI");
});

submitBtnNO.addEventListener("click", function() {
 submitBtnSI.setAttribute("disabled", "true");
 alert("Click en NO");
});
```

```html
<input id="SI" class="btn2"  type="submit" name="SI" value="SI" />
<input id="NO" class="btn2"  type="submit" name="NO" value="NO" />
```

Comment: muchas gracias por la ayuda amigo, pero como son submit cuando les doi click  me actualizan la pagina, y cuando doy click en "si", no se bloquea el boton "NO"  ete comento que el boton "SI" tiene una función que cambia el estado de 0 a 1, entonces he usado la opcion event.preventDefault  pero me quita la esa función del submit no se si me doi a entender

Comment: No, actualiza entonces tu codigo de la pregunta. Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta cuantas veces quieras. En tu codigo no hay ningúna funcion de 0 y 1. Pon el código completo y especifica bien que cual es el problema. Inicialmente dijiste que al darle click a SI se deshabilitara el NO permanentemente. Eso fue lo que hice. Aclara tu pregunta y pon el codigo completo

Comment: amigo ya actualice el código, espero haber sido mas claro muchas gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: amigo ya pude aclarar mi duda muchas gracias